# google-graph axis formatting

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts and want to place the x and y axes directly inside the graph, like this:

[BCG-Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Folio_Plot_BCG_Matrix_Example.png)

putting the axis into the center is possible with

```
hAxis: { baseline: 50 }
```

the axis title is however still at the bottom/side of the graph, even with

```
textposition: 'in'
```

I'd also appreciate nicer axes (with arrowheads etc.), and nicer bubble shapes! There is only

```
 bubble: { textStyle: { fontSize: 11 }, opacity: 0.8, stroke: '#ccc' }
```

I want to format the edge of the bubble, and move the bubble title outside of the bubble

Comment: aparently it's not possible with google charts, so I did it with D3.js